# Invoke activity on orientation change without restarting current activity

Tags: android, rotation

I have an app with many activities and which has layouts appropriate for both phone-sized (SFF) and tablet-sized (LFF) devices. For LFF devices, the framework's automatic recreation of activities upon orientation changes (landscape <-> portrait) works just fine and does what I want. When operating on an SFF device, I can lock the orientation as portrait, using [`Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)).

When running on an SFF device, I want to launch a different activity when the device is physically rotated into landscape orientation. (Let's leave aside discussions about whether it is a good design principle to launch a different activity upon rotation.)

Initially I used an [`OrientationEventListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html) to monitor the rotation but this fails in the case of an SFF device whose "natural" orientation is landscape. `OrientationEventListener.onOrientationChanged()` will report 0 degrees (+/-45) and `WindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` will report [`Surface.ROTATION_0`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#ROTATION_0) when in landscape orientation. I cannot find a way to determine the device's "natural" orientation in order to compensate for the reported rotation values. There are a couple of SO questions that discuss this but none seem to have a satisfactory answer.

Another option would be to use [`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) in the manifest and catch the orientation change in [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)). The problem with this is that it defeats the default behaviour for LFF devices and which I wish to retain. A horrible hack does present itself: duplicate each activity in the manifest with LFF and SFF versions, one with and one without the `android:configChanges` set, and then have the activity pick the appropriate version each time it launches a new activity.

My current solution uses neither `android:configChanges` nor `setRequestedOrientation()` and an `OrientationEventListener`. Instead I have a boolean resource, `is_landscape`, defined in `values-land` and I test this in the relevant Activities' `onCreate()`. This has the disadvantages that, upon rotation to landscape:

- the portrait-only activity that is about to launch the landscape activity, first gets recreated by the framework, which is reasonably expensive and can delay the launch of the landscape activity; and
- the portrait-only activity will lose some state that would otherwise usually have been retained by the framework and have been available upon return from the landscape activity.

Can anyone propose a better solution, including possibly a way to discover a device's "natural" orientation? I need this to work back to Android 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the natural orentation using a combination of `getRotation` and `getResources().getConfiguration()`.

```
public int getDefaultOrientation() {
    WindowManager windowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    if ( ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) &&
            config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        || ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) &&    
            config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
      return Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else { 
      return Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this really work if  `Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` has been called?

Comment: Actually it does not, but no matter. As I can call the code you suggest to discover the natural orientation before I ever call `Activity.setRequestedOrientation()` then this is sufficient. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.